# os.renames for ftp in python

Tags: python, file-upload, ftp

I want to move a large number of files from a windows system to a unix ftp server using python. I have a csv which has the current full path and filename and the new base bath to send it to (see [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/896379-replace-illegal-database-characters-with-_-in-one-go.html?p=3107698) for an example dataset).

I have got a script using os.renames to do the transfer and directory creation in windows but can figure out a way to easily do it via ftp.

```
import os, glob, arcpy, csv, sys, shutil, datetime
top=os.getcwd()
RootOutput = top
startpath=top
FileList = csv.reader(open('FileList.csv'))
filecount=0
successcount=0
errorcount=0

# Copy/Move to FTP when required
ftp = ftplib.FTP('xxxxxx')
ftp.login('xxxx', 'xxxx')
directory = '/TransferredData'
ftp.cwd(directory)

##f = open(RootOutput+'\\Success_LOG.txt', 'a')
##f.write("Log of files Succesfully processed. RESULT of process run @:"+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n")
##f.close()
##
for File in FileList:
    infile=File[0]
    # local network ver
    #outfile=RootOutput+File[4]
    #os.renames(infile, outfile)

    # ftp netowrk ver
#    outfile=RootOutput+File[4]
#    ftp.mkd(directory)

    print infile, outfile
```

I tried the process in http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/17047-Upload-file-to-FTP-using-Python-ftplib but this is for moving all files in a directory, I have the old and new full file names and just need it to create the intermediate directories.

Thanks,

Comment: I would create an archive locally, move it to the ftp server, and unpack the archive server-side. Or mount the ftp server as a drive letter and use local API. You could implement [`os.makedirs()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d9255c100971/Lib/os.py#l242) using `mkd`, `isdir` primitives or use a high-level interface such as [`fs.ftpfs`](http://code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem/).

Comment: Thanks. The problem with a zip is that it is close to Tb of data. If this is the only way then that's ok - can split it but it would be great if there was an alternative to os.makedirs()

Comment: What about the other two options (mount as Windows drive or try pyfilesystem)?

Answer (score 1):

The following might work (untested):

```
def mkpath(ftp, path):
    path = path.rsplit('/', 1)[0] # parent directory
    if not path:
        return
    try:
        ftp.cwd(path)
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        mkpath(ftp, path)
        ftp.mkd(path)

ftp = FTP(...)
directory = '/TransferredData/'

for File in FileList:
    infile = File[0]
    outfile = File[4].split('\\') # need forward slashes in FTP
    outfile = directory + '/'.join(outfile)
    mkpath(ftp, outfile)
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+outfile, open(infile, 'rb'))
```