# Difference between except: and except Exception as e:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Both the following snippets of code do the same thing. They catch every exception and execute the code in the `except:` block

Snippet 1 -

```
try:
    #some code that may throw an exception
except:
    #exception handling code
```

Snippet 2 -

```
try:
    #some code that may throw an exception
except Exception as e:
    #exception handling code
```

What is exactly the difference in both the constructs?

Comment: @user2725093 that's not the same question. The one you linked to asks what's the difference between
`except Exception, e:` and `except Exception as e:`.
This question asks what the difference is between
`except:` and `except Exception as e:`.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

In the second you can access the attributes of the exception object:

```
>>> def catch():
...     try:
...         asd()
...     except Exception as e:
...         print e.message, e.args
... 
>>> catch()
global name 'asd' is not defined ("global name 'asd' is not defined",)
```

But it doesn't catch `BaseException` or the system-exiting exceptions `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `GeneratorExit`:

```
>>> def catch():
...     try:
...         raise BaseException()
...     except Exception as e:
...         print e.message, e.args
... 
>>> catch()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in catch
BaseException
```

Which a bare except does:

```
>>> def catch():
...     try:
...         raise BaseException()
...     except:
...         pass
... 
>>> catch()
>>>
```

See the [Built-in Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) section of the docs and the [Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) section of the tutorial for more info.

Comment: Well, there's no magic here. ``Exception`` is derived from ``BaseException``, that's why ``except Exception`` does not catch ``BaseException``. If you write ``except BaseException``, it'll be caught too. Bare ``except`` just catches everything.

Comment: I should point out that a bare `except` must be last in a series of `except` blocks, while you won't get an error if you put `except Exception` before other `except` blocks: they'll just get ignored silently (if they handle `Exception` subclasses). Something to watch out for.

Comment: @MatthewPhipps That's sort of the point, isn't it? like case statements or if-else blocks, execution jumps to the first condition that matches...

Comment: @Basic Just pointing out another difference between bare `except` and `except Exception`. "Something to watch out for" looks a little weird now, but at the time I expected Python to pick the most specific `except` block, regardless of where it was, and was a little disappointed to find out otherwise.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the second form should only be used if you do not care about what the exception was or wish to handle it in a meaningful way.

Comment: @JoshJ Can you clarify what you mean? The "second form" in the original question is the one that captures the exception to an object, so not sure why in that one would would be if you didn't care what the exception is.

Comment: @agf I meant the second form in this answer since the answer lists them opposite of the original question.

Comment: Note: this is for python 2

Answer (score 94):

```
except:
```

accepts **all** exceptions, whereas

```
except Exception as e:
```

only accepts exceptions that you're *meant* to catch.

Here's an example of one that you're not meant to catch:

```
>>> try:
...     input()
... except:
...     pass
... 
>>> try:
...     input()
... except Exception as e:
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The first one silenced the `KeyboardInterrupt`!

Here's a quick list:

```
issubclass(BaseException, BaseException)
#>>> True
issubclass(BaseException, Exception)
#>>> False


issubclass(KeyboardInterrupt, BaseException)
#>>> True
issubclass(KeyboardInterrupt, Exception)
#>>> False


issubclass(SystemExit, BaseException)
#>>> True
issubclass(SystemExit, Exception)
#>>> False
```

If you want to catch any of those, it's best to do

```
except BaseException:
```

to point out that you know what you're doing.

---

**All** exceptions stem from `BaseException`, and those you're meant to catch day-to-day (those that'll be thrown *for* the programmer) inherit too from `Exception`.

Comment: `except(Exception)` never catches `KeyboardInterrupt` errors. `as e` doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: I never said that it did. I haven't once mentioned the `as e`, because I assumed it's obvious what it does.

Comment: Is there a case where a person would catch BaseException AND know what they are doing?

Comment: @Davos Yeah, you might prefer it when doing transient logging, or if you're offering a console to the user that you don't want exceptions like `SystemExit` or `KeyboardInterrupt` to escape from. Not a common case, but it does happen.

Answer (score 21):

There are differences with some exceptions, e.g. KeyboardInterrupt.

Reading [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> A bare except: clause will catch SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt
>   exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with Control-C,
>   and can disguise other problems. If you want to catch all exceptions
>   that signal program errors, use except Exception: (bare except is
>   equivalent to except BaseException:).

Answer (score 8):

Another way to look at this. Check out the details of the exception:

```
In [49]: try: 
    ...:     open('file.DNE.txt') 
    ...: except Exception as  e: 
    ...:     print(dir(e)) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                    
['__cause__', '__class__', '__context__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__suppress_context__', '__traceback__', 'args', 'characters_written', 'errno', 'filename', 'filename2', 'strerror', 'with_traceback']
```

There are lots of "things" to access using the 'as e' syntax.

This code was solely meant to show the details of this instance.

Answer (score 5):

Using the second snippet gives you a variable (named based upon the `as` clause, in your example `e`) in the `except` block scope with the exception object bound to it so you can use the information in the exception (type, message, stack trace, etc) to handle the exception in a more specially tailored manor.