# Try-except code block needs optimization

Tags: python, refactoring, try-catch

At below, I have a try-except block that I want to refactor it. As you see, it is not pythonic and not-maintainable.

```
 try:
     try:
         foo()
     except xError:
         doSth()
         raise
 except:
     exc_type = sys.exc_info()[0]
     if exc_type == FooError:
         doBlaBla()
     else:   
         doFlaFla() 

     blablabla()       # whatever the exceptions is, run this code block
     foobar()
     zoo()
     ...
```

I change that block as the below code;

```
 try:
     try:
         foo()
     except xError:
         doSth()
         raise
 except FooError:
     doBlaBla()
     raise
 except:
     doFlaFla() 
     raise

     blablabla()       # This is where the problem happens for me.
     foobar()
     zoo()
     ...
```

As you can see, I need a **except-finally** like operation. It will not run when no exception raises but any exceptions. What do you advice ? How should I change this clode block ?

Comment: Why you've used innder try exempt block?

Comment: How is anything supposed to happen after you re-raise the error? The line `# do bla bla` appears unreachable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is what i'm asking for! Where should that code block stay ?

Comment: Your `do bla bla` is only ever executed when `FooError` is caught. Move it to *that block*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are u kidding me ? It should work for any exception case!

Comment: @myildirim: *It doesn't*. Not in the code you posted, because the `raise` is executed, exiting the current code flow.

Comment: @myildirim: removing the `raise` changed your question significantly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, sorry for the prior and wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

Why you've used innder try exempt block?
In my opinion, it is a good practice to put finally except statement, that will catch unexpected error.

So I suggest:

```
try:
    fn()
except Exception1:
    do stuff you want
except Exception 2:
    do another stuff
except Exception as e:
    # Here you will catch an unexpected error, and you can log it
    raise UnknownError -> do stuff you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your exception-code in a try-finally block, for example:

```
try:
    try:
        foo()
    except xError:
        doSth()
        raise
# catch Exception to avoid catching system errors
except Exception as e:
    try:
        if isinstance(e, FooError):
            doBlaBla()
        else:   
            doFlaFla() 
            raise
    finally:
        # this will always run regardless of what you raise
```

Another approach could be something like this:

```
e = None
try:
    try:
        foo()
    except xError:
        doSth()
        raise
except FooError as e:
    doBlaBla()
except Exception as e:
    doFlaFla() 
    raise
finally:
    # this will always run regardless of what you raise
    if e:
        # exception took place...
```

Comment: As far as i escape from the nested-try blocks, but it seems, it could work.

Comment: If you want to split the `except` blocks then your best bet is to put the "common" code in a function and call it in each `except` block.

Comment: I am already aware of it,but, actual code base is much larger and not-seperatable. Anyway, thanks for answer.

Comment: Perhaps the other approach in my edited answer is more what you're looking for?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Because, your "except Exception as e:" statement overrides my custom exceptions and causes to lose the main reason of the error.So, I can just see the generic Exception.

Comment: `Exception` is just the superclass of exceptions in Python, your custom exception's type isn't changed if that's your concern

Comment: Ahh, I checked it, you are right. I thought that it overrides the original error but it doesn't! Thanks.

Comment: But, there is another problem here, please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982610/difference-between-except-and-except-exception-as-e-in-python

Comment: It's not really an issue. In general, you should only worry about catching non-system-exiting exceptions and not system errors (like `KeyboardInterrupt` and other uncontrollable errors).

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
def others():
    """Other stuff to do when non-xError occurs.""" 
    blablabla()
    foobar()
    zoo()
```

and then factor into a single `try`:

```
try:
    foo()
except xError:
    doSth()
    raise
except FooError:
    doBlaBla()
    others()
except Exception:
    doFlaFla()
    others()
```

A bare `except` is [usually a bad idea](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/).

Comment: Because it is not as easy as this. The 'others' code block has many dependencies, so it can not be seperated.

Comment: What "dependencies"? Can you refactor to remove them (e.g. using explicit parameters and `return` values)? In a more general sense, how on earth do you expect anyone to help you refactor your code when you don't provide enough information on what you already have?