# What's the difference between "KeyError" and "KeyError as e"?

Tags: python, django, try-catch

When writing try/except statements, whether I use

```
except KeyError:
```

or

```
except KeyError as e:
```

I get the same result.

What is the difference between the two? Is `KeyError as e` just more specific/custom?

Comment: You get the actual exception object as the variable `e`. Apart from that, there is no difference.

Comment: Ok cool well put I see what you mean.

Comment: You can often avoid sounding stupid by [reading the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and answering the question yourself!

Comment: Ha thank you for the tip will do!

Comment: Here's an elaborate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982610/difference-between-except-and-except-exception-as-e-in-python#answer-18982726

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `except KeyError as e:`, you can access the exception and its attributes as an object with `e`. Like so:

```
def test_function():
    try:
        do_something_that_fails()
    except Exception as e:
        print e.message, e.args
```

It will help with debugging any problems you have when the exception is thrown.

You can find more information on how this works in the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Good luck!