# What does ''except Exception as e'' mean in python?

Tags: python, exception, semantics

The typical structure for exception handling is below:

```
try:
    pass
except Exception, e:
    raise
else:
    pass
finally:
    pass
```

May I know what does `except Exception, e:`or`except Exception as e:` mean?
Typically I will use `print (e)` to print the error message but I am wondering what the program has done to generate the e.

If I were to construct it in another way (below), how would it be like?

```
except Exception:
    e = Exception.something
```

What should the method be to replace the `something`?

When the body of code under `try` gives no exception, the program will execute the code under `else`. But, what does `finally` do here?

Comment: There sure are a lot of questions in the question.  I would recommend you read the documentation for `try`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement  That will answer most of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between except: and except Exception as e: in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982610/difference-between-except-and-except-exception-as-e-in-python)

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`except Exception as e`, or `except Exception, e` (Python 2.x only) means that it catches exceptions of type `Exception`, and in the `except:` block, the exception that was raised (the actual object, not the exception class) is bound to the variable `e`.

As for `finally`, it's a block that *always* gets executed, regardless of what happens, after the `except` block (if an exception is raised) but always before anything else that would jump out of the scope is triggered (e.g. `return`, `continue` or `raise`).

Comment: Is "except Exception, e:" same as "except Exception as e:"? And does the 1st example catch base exceptions?

Comment: Both forms do the exact same thing. Neither catches base exceptions (e.g. `SystemExit` or `KeyboardInterrupt`, which inherit from `BaseException` but not from `Exception`). If you're raising things that *don't* inherit from `BaseException` (in Python 2 you can raise arbitrary objects, e.g. strings, but you shouldn't), they won't be caught either.