# Why is "except:" able to catch this error but not "except Exception, e:"?

Tags: python, fabric

I have the following file:

```
from fabric.api import env, execute, run

env.hosts = ['1.2.3.4']

def taskA():
    run('ls')

def main():
  try:
    execute(taskA)
  except:
    print "Exception Caught"

main()
```

I am able to see "Exception Caught" printed when I run this:

```
$ python test.py
[1.2.3.4] Executing task 'taskA'
[1.2.3.4] run: ls

Fatal error: Timed out trying to connect to 1.2.3.4 (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
    timed out

Aborting.
Exception Caught
```

However, when I switch it to this:

```
def main():
  try:
    execute(taskA)
  except Exception, e:
    print "Exception Caught", e

main()
```

I don't see the exception being caught:

```
[1.2.3.4] run: ls

Fatal error: Timed out trying to connect to 1.2.3.4 (tried 1 time)

Underlying exception:
    timed out

Aborting.
```

Is there a reason why I am able to catch the error in the code above and not below?

Comment: I don't see a traceback, so the exception *was* caught. Are you sure you are printing correctly? Also, use `except Exception as e:`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No traceback probably means it's a SystemExit.

Comment: @user2357112 good point!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This exception does not derive from `Exception`. It looks like a `SystemExit`, which derives from `BaseException` directly. `except Exception` only catches instances of `Exception`.

If you really want to catch absolutely all exceptions, you can do that with

```
except BaseException as e:
```

---

`SystemExit` is thrown by `sys.exit` and a few similar functions to cause an interpreter shutdown (or at least end the thread) while still running `__exit__` methods and `finally` blocks. It can also be thrown manually.

`BaseException` exists so `SystemExit` and a few similar exceptions aren't caught by `except Exception` blocks that usually aren't intended to handle them. It's similar to Java's `Throwable`. Personally, I wish plain `except:` blocks didn't catch `BaseException`; it defeats some of the purpose of having `BaseException` in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

When you use `except Exception, e`, it

> doesn't catch `BaseException` or the system-exiting exceptions
>   `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `GeneratorExit`

where as `except` catches all exception types. See [Difference between except: and except Exception as e: in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982610/difference-between-except-and-except-exception-as-e-in-python).

As a result you see "Exception Caught" when using `except`, however not when using `except Exception, e`

From the fab [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/fab.html?highlight=exception)

> If a Python exception is thrown, fab aborts with an exit status of 1.