# Geocoding in python get Latitude and Longitude from addresses using API key

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, google-api, jupyter-notebook, geocode

I currently have a data frame that has address details of certain place. I want to use Google geocode API key to find the coordinates - Latitude and Longitude in order to plot a map. Does anybody know how to do this? I have tried the below code but it is returning 'Error, skipping address...' on all the lines of addresses.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from geopy import geocoders
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

API_KEY = os.getenv("API1234")
g = GoogleV3(api_key=API_KEY)


loc_coordinates = []
loc_address = []

for address in df.Address:
    try:
        inputAddress = Address
        location = g.geocode(inputAddress, timeout=15)
        loc_coordinates.append((location.latitude, location.longitude))
        loc_Address.append(inputAddress)
    except:
        print('Error, skipping address...')


df_geocodes = pd.DataFrame({'coordinate':loc_coordinates,'address':loc_address})
```

Comment: Two things up front:  
1. This is possibly just a copy-paste error but you've written ```inputAddress = Address``` when I suppose you meant ```inputAddress = address```, so as to not assign a type to that variable but the variable of your for-loop.  
2. instead of printing 'Error, skipping address...' in the except clause, try catching the actual exception, which might give you more of a hint what is going wrong (I bet it's a TypeError in the line after the inputAddress assignment). You would do ```except Exception as e:``` and then print infos about the actual exception.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982610/difference-between-except-and-except-exception-as-e-in-python) for further reference.

Answer (score 2):

You had some typos: `Address` instead of `address`, `loc_Address` instead of `loc_address`.

But what is `df.Address` ?

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from geopy import geocoders
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

API_KEY = os.getenv("API1234")
g = GoogleV3(api_key=API_KEY)


loc_coordinates = []
loc_address = []
for address in df.Address:
    try:
        inputAddress = address
        location = g.geocode(inputAddress, timeout=15)
        loc_coordinates.append((location.latitude, location.longitude))
        loc_address.append(inputAddress)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error, skipping address...', e)


df_geocodes = pd.DataFrame({'coordinate':loc_coordinates,'address':loc_address})
```

Comment: Thank you for this! df.Address df is my dataframe that I am working on and Address is the column in which I am trying to get the Latitude and Longitude

Comment: I have declared it in the row above import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
df.Address = pd.read_csv("")

Comment: I am still however getting 'Error, Skipping Address' once I run the code with the given corrections

Comment: Can you add a `print(df.Address)` before the for loop and show me what it says ?

Comment: I will try that now

Comment: It prints out the below statement 
Empty DataFrame
    Columns: [address, coordinate]
    Index: []
    Error, skipping address...

Comment: OK, so the problem is that you don't have any addresses in `df.Address`. Probably you are not reading correctly the csv

Comment: If you replace `for address in df.Address:` with `for address in `["55 Rue d'Amsterdam, Paris"]:` for example and you add a `print(df_geocodes)` at the end, you will see the address and the coordinates

Comment: I have re ran the code that calls the dataframe and it now prints all the addresses however once I remove the statement print(df.Address) I'm getting Error, Skipping address @Robert  D. Mogos

Comment: once I done that it printed     address                coordinate
0  Address2   (41.088137, -81.544786)
1  Postcode   (53.8074595, -1.524806)
2       LCG  (39.047906, -77.1206027)

Comment: I updated the answer, can you copy that code and show the new output?

Comment: I have tried that and it is printing out my whole data frame and after the 339 rows and columns that it prints it states:     
('Geoloc ', 'PracNo')
('Geoloc ', 'PracticeName'
('Error, skipping address...', GeocoderQuotaExceeded('The given key has gone over the requests limit in the 24 hour period or has submitted too many requests in too short a period of time.',))

Comment: OK, so that's your problem. You are exceeding your query quota. You need a key that allows you to search addresses more often. Did you sign up for an API key on google ?

Comment: You need to sign up here and get a key https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start (Click on `Get a key` on the top right). After you get the key, replace `API_KEY = os.getenv("API1234")` with `API_KEY = "YOUR GOOGLE KEY"`

Comment: It still is coming out with an error ('Geoloc ', 'PracNo')
('Error, skipping address...', NameError("name 'address' is not defined",))
('Geoloc ', 'PracticeName')
('Error, skipping address...', NameError("name 'address' is not defined",))
('Geoloc ', 'Address1')
('Error, skipping address...', NameError("name 'address' is not defined",))
('Geoloc ', 'Address2')
('Error, skipping address...', NameError("name 'address' is not defined",))
('Geoloc ', 'Address3')
('Error, skipping address...', NameError("name 'address' is not defined",))
('Geoloc ', 'Postcode')

Comment: Just by adding the new key you get this or did you change something else ?