# Catch all exceptions except user abort

Tags: python, exception

I have a script that catches all exceptions, which works great unless I want to abort the script manually (with `control + c`). In this case the abort command appears to be caught by the exception instead of quitting.

Is there a way to exclude this type of error from the exception? For example something as follows:

```
try:
    do_thing()
except UserAbort:
    break
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    continue
```

Comment: `except Exception:` will not catch `KeyboardInterrupt` so ctrl + c would still work.

Answer (score 8):

You could just force to exit the program whenever the exception happens:

```
import sys
# ...
try:
    do_thing()
except UserAbort:
    break
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    continue
```

Comment: Wait, but the OP _wants_ ctrl + c to crash the program, right? "which works great unless I want to abort the script manually (with control + c)"

Comment: Yes @roganjosh I am trying to crash the program. I believe you are correct that catching a general `Exception` will not include `KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: @AlexG [It won't catch it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18982771/4799172)

Comment: Sorry about that, I've misread the question. A simply re-raise should fix though

Comment: I would be more comfortable doing `except KeyboardInterrupt as e` then using `raise e` instead just in case some module higher up in the call chain catches it...