# Python Error handling cant except error's

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying this code:

```
try:
    res = subprocess.Popen('bgpq3 -4 {} -m 24 -l {}'.format('MAIyNT- 
AS38082','12414'), shell=True,
    universal_newlines=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
except Exception:
       print("Wrong")
       #do this code
```

The output is ?

```
ERROR:Unable to parse prefix 'MAIyNT-AS38082', af=2 (inet), ret=0
ERROR:Unable to parse prefix MAIyNT-AS38082
ERROR:Unable to add prefix MAIyNT-AS38082 (bad prefix or address-family)
```

so i am not able to use Error handling!!

Any Idea?

Comment: Are those errors coming through `stderr`?

Comment: No because when i use the command without stderr and subprocess ! i get the same error

Comment: try:
    res = subprocess.Popen('bgpq3 -4 {} -m 24 -l {}'.format('MAIyNT- AS38082','12414') , shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
except Exception:
    print("Wrong")   this is work for me may be  you need to format code to properly

Comment: bgpq3 -4 MAIyNT-AS38082 -m 24 -l AS38082    Results the same error

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You're only handling errors of type `exception` here. You only need to use `except:`. This way you're catching all errors that occur in the code.

```
try:
    #your code
except Exception as e:
    #handle the exception
```

For more information refer to [the docs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm) I got from a quick google ;)

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. @Gsk I was only suggesting as a quick dirty fix. I edited my answer. Although yours is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

when you write `except Exception:` you are not catching *all* the exception: the system exit errors and OS errors (as `BaseException`, `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `GeneratorExit`) [are excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982610/difference-between-except-and-except-exception-as-e-in-python).

Most of the exceptions of subprocess are [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#exceptions).
Since you did not report the full traceback of the error, I may only assume that you're getting one of these errors, and you can catch them using:

```
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
```

or

```
except OSError:
```

as [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#exception-names) suggest, you should NOT use `except:` alone, even if it will work in your case.
As a rule of thumb, always catch the *exact* exception you espect to be raised!

Comment: don't you have also a line where the error occurs or something else?