# What the difference between bare-except and broad-except in Python

Tags: python

In Python, we can write two kinds of exceptions handling logics

First one is bare except:

```
try:
   do_something()
except:
   error_handling()
```

Another one is First broad except:

```
try:
   do_something()
except Exception:
   error_handling()
```

What's the actual difference between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between except: and except Exception as e: in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982610/difference-between-except-and-except-exception-as-e-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

The top of the exception hierarchy is not `Exception`, but `BaseException`, which  has four subclasses:

- `Exception`
- `GeneratorExit`
- `SystemExit`
- `KeyboardInterrupt`

A bare `except:` is equivalent to `except BaseException:`.