# How can I create a directory with SCPClient

Tags: python, paramiko, scp

I am trying to upload files to a remote server using `SCPClient`. It fails if the target directory does not exist

```
from scp import SCPClient, SCPException
...
with SCPClient(self.client.get_transport()) as scp:
    scp.put(source_path, target_path)
```

I am struggling to find documentation or examples that would help clarify this. Are there resources that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using [scp module for paramiko](https://pypi.org/project/scp/). It does not seem to support working with directories.

---

If you really need to use SCP protocol, you can try [scpclient library](https://pypi.org/project/scpclient/). It also does not have an explicit way to create a directory. After all, that's not what SCP protocol is designed for.

But as your task seems to be to upload a directory – do so, upload a directory, not files:

```
with closing(WriteDir(ssh_client.get_transport(), "/target/dir")) as scp:
    scp.send_dir('/source/dir')
```

That will cause the directory to be implicitly created (if it does not exist yet) as a part of the upload.

---

Though I would suggest you use SFTP protocol instead. It's built into Paramiko. So you won't need any external libraries. And SFTP supports everything you will ever need (contrary to SCP).

See [Upload files using SFTP in Python, but create directories if path doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14819681/850848).

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go. My objective is to only upload files that have changed since the last upload. Sometimes that requires creating a directory/

Comment: That will be difficult to implement with SCP. Use SFTP.

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct because you pointed me in the right direction. I needed SFTP. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819681/upload-files-using-sftp-in-python-but-create-directories-if-path-doesnt-exist) gave me the code I was looking for